# Stripped twin paradox

Tags: special-relativity, relativity

Consider an empty space, except for Alice and Bob.

Suppose Alice sees Bob move away and then come back again.
Suppose Bob sees Alice move away and then come back again.

Suppose either of them will feel an acceleration and the other won't.

Which one will feel the acceleration?

Clearly the acceleration they feel cannot be a result of the acceleration measured, since both parties will see the other accelerate towards them at some point.

Given that experienced acceleration cannot come from measured acceleration, how can we trust an accelerometer to give us actual acceleration (as measured) instead of experienced acceleration?

On what basis can we say that either of them accelerates?

Comment: Whichever one, in their spaceships, observes stronger fictitious forces on free objects. Accelerating frames aren't indistinguishable like inertial frames are.

Comment: @Brionius if you are saying the one which observes stronger forces is the one which feels more acceleration, then your answer is tautologous and uninformative. Relativity theory should make a prediction based on physical facts.

Comment: No, I'm saying Alice can set a marble at rest in front of her, and measure its acceleration, and Bob can do the same - whichever one observes a greater marble acceleration is the one whose spaceship itself is accelerating more. What's tautologous about that? Maybe I don't understand the question? Are you asking "Two objects move. Which one accelerates more"? In that case, you...haven't included enough information to make that question answerable.

Comment: The 'aether'? You might want to read up on its non-existence.

Comment: Angelorf, why don't you 'ask' the accelerometer's attached to Alice and Bob?

Comment: it's both a twin paradox and a 2 bodies problem. There are only 2 possible frames. How can Alice accelerate ? Neglecting the free falls, without external energy, Alice must split herself. In this case, each part feels the acceleration if it is composite or by tracking the other part. Bob sees Alice_1 and Alice_2 moving away from each other and feels something only if he has some empathy for Alice.

Comment: @Gert: "We may say that according to the general theory of relativity space is endowed with physical qualities; in this sense, therefore, there exists an aether." - Einstein

Comment: @Brionius: your method is after the fact. You suppose one is accelerating more and provide a method to find this acceleration. My question is on what basis can one assign an acceleration to either in the first place?

Comment: I'm sorry, I have no idea what you mean by "assign acceleration". It seems like my method will work whether Alice is accelerating more, Bob is accelerating more, or they're accelerating at the same rate. I don't understand your comment about "the one with more mass". Why would the mass of either Alice or Bob restrict one from accelerating more than the other? **We** can't know *before the fact* whether Alice or Bob will accelerate more - it's **your** thought experiment! I guess "Alice" sounds like a speedier name than "Bob", so...Alice?

Comment: @Brionius we can assign an acceleration to any object standing still when we take an accelerating frame of reference. Of course this won't result in any change to an accelerometer attached to the object. In order to distinguish an intertial frame of reference from an accelerating frame of reference I must assume the existence of some kind of aether - not one which assigns an objective velocity to the frame of reference, but one which assigns an objective acceleration. Does an aether in that sense exist?

Comment: @Angelorf Don't use accelerating frames in SR. If you do use them there will be fictitious forces, and Brionius is correct that you can detect fictitious forces, use a spring: if it behaves one way you are moving inertially, if it acts differently you are not moving inertially. The fact is you are either moving inertially or not, and *local* experiments can determine which you are doing. The local experiments don't *cause* the motion, they *detect* the motion. You have simply *underspecified* your problem

Comment: As posed, the question cannot be answered unambiguously - as discussed by Brionius and Timaeus's comments in particular. For this reason I vote to close this question as "unclear", encouraging you to add more details until it becomes a question that has a physical answer.

Comment: What details would I have to add so that it becomes a question that has a physical answer? That's my question.

Comment: @Angelorf Don't edit a question to invalidate existing correct answers. Figure out what physics concept you want to learn. Then start by looking for existing questions about the same concept. If the existing questions and answers don't fully satisfy what you wanted to learn, then write a *new* question about it and focus on exactly what you want to learn that existing questions and answers didn't cover.

Comment: @Timaeus I'm not editing the question to invalidate your answer; I'm editing my question to make my question more clear, which also makes clear why your answer is insufficient to solve the problem I'm struggling with.

Comment: The new question comes down to the same thing. Suppose that indeed the answer was "the one with the most mass", then the answer to the question what information is needed would be "the mass of Alice and Bob".

Comment: Still it might be too difficult to abstract the problem I'm struggling with from the question I posed. I'm okay with the question being deleted. Is that possible?

Comment: @Angelorf You answered your *own* question, then edited your own question to invalidate your own answer. And the answer is that you have it all backwards, accelerations cause the changes in relative velocities that cause the changes in relative position. And no, your edit makes zero impact on my answer, which still correctly tells you that you have the cart before the horse. And your question still is not about a physics concept

Comment: But how can you say which one is accelerating? For either the other seems to be accelerating.

Comment: @Angelorf That's not true. They send and receive signals. They can feel their own acceleration. They could ask the other one what the other one feels. But the other one has to wait to get the message, might not respond, or might even lie and then you have to wait for the reply. And fundamentally you can't just tell when something else is accelerating. You have to model what it would appear like to you if it did or didn't accelerate and then compare your actual observations to the observations you model predicts you would make. And in your case you underspecified so who knows what's happening.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34127/discussion-on-question-by-angelorf-stripped-twin-paradox).

Answer (score 1):

Since your title mentions the twin paradox. Let's review that.

Let's say Alice moves inertially while sending light signals to Bob every x units of Alice proper time.

And let's say Bob starts out moving away from Alice and at some point on Bob's clock, Bob accelerates towards Alice to eventually meet up while sending light signals to Alice every x units of Bob proper time on all stages of the mission (heading out and coming back and accelerating too).

In this case Bob will start to receive signals from Alice at a faster rate than before as soon as he starts to slow down. And once he is at rest relative to Alice he gets them at the same rate as he sends them. And on the way back he gets them at a faster rate from Alice than he sends them to Alice. Each time, the relative rates of receiving signals versus sending signals changes as soon as Bob accelerates, right where and when Bob accelerates.

But Alice won't start to get signals from Bob more often than she sends them to Bob until after she *gets* the signals sent after Bob was moving closer (whereas Bob starts getting a flipped rate as soon as he *sends* that signal).

Again. This is literally how they can send each other different numbers of birthday cards.

The situation is **not at all** symmetric. Bob can tell the instant he accelerates. He starts to get signals from Alice at a different rate as soon as he accelerates, so it happens half way through his journey.

Whereas Alice only gets signals at a faster rate than sending them when much more than half the waiting time as passed.

As always: draw the spacetime diagram.

---

*Your problem* is simply underspecified. The only difference you describe is their name. So there can't possibly be an answer. And it's the accelerations that cause the results about how their relative separations change over time. If you want to detect the accelerations you could do that. If they are exerting forces on each other to move you might think the more massive one accelerates less, however distant objects can't exert forces on each directly. If the objects were charged for instance, then each of them exchanges energy and momentum with the electromagnetic field, the electromagnetic field carries energy and momentum through space and then it gives energy and momentum to the other charge.

But now which one accelerates more depends on the mass and the charge and their history. For instance they might even basically take turns accelerating.

And anyway, everything about your question is just vagueness. For instance the empty space is irrelevant. If you have other objects far far away that don't interact, then the two objects in question move the same way. Ignorance isn't a cause any more than vagueness is a cause. Just becasue you close your eyes doesn't make you move differently, and this isn't a cartoon where a force doesn't act on you unless you pay enough attention to whether it is supposed to affect you.

And your new question still has it all backwards. Mass can't be responsible since there are examples where the less massive one accelerates more and examples where the more massive one accelerates more. And nothing can responsible since the casuality is forces and mass cause accelerations and accelerations cause changes in velocity and velocities cause changes in position. And they can't exert forces directly when they are far apart, so your situation doesn't even happen.

> Clearly the acceleration they feel cannot be a result of the acceleration measured,

You seem to have a very deep confusion about causality. Forces cause accelerations. Measurements of acceleration don't cause accelerations, they reveal accelerations that were already happening.

> since both parties will see the other accelerate towards them at some point.

And you don't see other things accelerate. You can feel and measure yourself accelerate and you can send signals to others and get signals from others and you can influence other things far away by interacting with something by you (such as a field) that can affect things by it and so on until the far away thing is affected. Which then happens much later.

> Given that experienced acceleration cannot come from measured acceleration,

Who would even think that. That would be like saying paying attention to electromagnetism caused charges to move apart.

> how can we trust an accelerometer to give us actual acceleration (as measured) instead of experienced acceleration?

What is this magical difference between actual and measured? Don't call it a measurement unless the result is what happened.

> On what basis can we say that either of them accelerates?

If neither of them accelerated, then SR doesn't allow them to move apart and come back together. But they couldn't accelerate, since they can't exert forces becasue they are in an empty universe and direct action at a distance isn't a thing. So your situation didn't happen.

It's like asking how an invisible pink unicorn can be invisible and pink. There is no such unicorn.

In the real world, for instance two charges and some field everywhere. The world is not empty. The charges can affect the fields. The fiekds can affect themselves. The fields can affect the charges. And things have positions in the flat spacetime manifold, and velocities (tangent vectors to their world lines) and accelerations. And the accelerations are given by the forces. And they affect the velocities. And the velocities determine the positions in the manifold. And that's that.

Since you presumably know this. You know exactly what us happening, and why, and how. So you should not have any more questions.

And let's be clear. If you actually told us what they saw, we likely would be able to tell. Just. Like. The. Example. I. Started. With.

The twin scenario starts to get signals at a different rate than sending them when they accelerate, the other one only sees a change in relative rates after they get a message that happens during the other twins acceleration. That's a some data that reveals which is accelerating. It didn't cause the acceleration.

Comment: Your answer seems to purposfully ignore my question and just reviews the twin paradox itself.
"Bob can tell the instant he accelerates." But on which basis does relativity theory predict which one will be undergoing an acceleration?

Comment: @Angelorf I think this answer is as good as it's going to get - you need to add details to your question for it to be answerable.

Comment: Example: Suppose you put Alice and Bob on a mechanical balance; which one will move down? The one weighing more. Underspecified questions can still get answers.

Comment: @Angelorf There is no such thing as *down* in an empty space, so you can't set things "down" on a scale. And there is nothing to make the scale move in an empty space. And mass is not defined by what a scale does. Again, you have everything backwards. And as for your new question, I already answered it by telling you have it all backwards. And to be on topic questions are supposed to be about a physics concept you want to learn. Yours is written as if you are trying to get us to do a badly written homework problem for us, or help you write a novel. I see no evidence you want to learn physics.

Comment: You totally misunderstood the point of my example. Never mind that. By telling me I have it all backwards you are not solving my problem at all. If you can only answer my question with a badly written homework solution, then I don't think this question is for you to answer.

Comment: @Angelorf It's not a badly written homework solution, that implies the question was good. It is a correct, timely, and relevant education about the fact that you have your concepts in a complete mess and how to think about it properly. Which from your own answer you already knew. Forces can't be magically transmitted across distances, they must be mediated. Forces and mass together cause accelerations. Accelerations cause changes in velocities. Velocities cause changes in position. Hence that's where relative position changes come from. You have it all backwards.

Comment: I'm not accusing you of badly writing an answer. You totally misunderstood me. Your answer is quite well written. The problem is that it doesn't solve my problem, since it presumes that Bob accelerates. Relativity theory links a force to an acceleration, but the acceleration can only be measured through forces, so RT might be seen to introduce a ghost variable (acceleration). Acceleration can certainly not be measured through A or B, since that would result in a symmetric situation, in which the acceleration is assigned to both. That is why I'm asking how acceleration can be grounded.

Comment: @Angelorf No, you misunderstand me. And I keep saying the same thing. You have every ... single ... concept  backwards. Relativity doesn't link accelerations to forces, dynamics does. And yes, dynamics tells us that A and B *can* measure and detect their accelerations. And you never actually stated that anything was symmetric at all, you just wrote it vaguely. My answer was to educate you about concepts and you haven't learned a single concept I tried to teach you. When you accelerate, you literally feel it, and you can detect it e.g. by watching springs change, there are even accelerometers.

Comment: You haven't seen any evidence of me learning anything from you because the actual twin paradox is not answering the problem I have. The folowing question might seem to you to be getting off subject, but it is really at the core of the hole in (my understanding of) relativity theory. How do you know that an accelerometer is giving you the value of change in velocity?

Comment: @Angelorf Did you read how there is nothing symmetric about the twin paradox when you look at what they actually see. Did you notice that you never stipulated in your question that anything is symmetric. Did you notice that you brig up symmetry in your comments? You haven't learned the regular twin paradox and you aren't trying to learn any physics concepts, and that's why you fail to learn anything. And when you have different questions, ask new questions. If you want to know how an accelerometer works, you can *ask*. But first check to see if it has been answered before.

Comment: How dare you say I haven't learned anything about the twin paradox. I haven't spilled a word on it and you just assume I don't understand it. I never stipulated in my question that anything is symmetric, but I didn't think I had to since the information I provided was perfectly symmetric. It doesn't matter how an accelerometer works internally. It's impossible to say that what a device is measuring is acceleration if acceleration depends on your frame of reference, which might itself be partly accelerating. I therefore conclude that it is impossible to say of anything that it is accelerating.

Comment: @Angelorf There is nothing symmetric about what people see in the twin paradox. And you don't mention anything being symmetric about what people see in your question. And yet you bring up symmetry in your comments. Hence you don't know anything. And again, I stated why I said, and you ignored me. Your situation wasn't symmetric, it was vague. Vague doesn't mean symmetric. If I fail to describe in detail what happens that doesn't mean that the situation is symmetric. Acceleration doesn't depend on your inertial frame, and you can tell if something is accelerating with an accelerometer.

Comment: @Angelorf Ask a separate question if you fail to understand how to detect if you are on a spinning merry go round, hint, look for fictitious forces. And you can detect the acceleration using equipment that is also accelerating. Accelerometers work while accelerating. It's kind of essential.

Comment: I have said multiple times already that my question is not about the ordinary twin paradox, but you keep on coming back to it. This is futile.

Comment: @Angelorf Its your opinion that you understand the original setup, but since you think they are symmetric you don't understand the original. & since you think removing far away objects makes a difference, you actually have an incorrect machian view of SR. And since you are so biased that you think accelerates don't work you think acceleration is relative. Whereas you need to learn SR and proper definitions and learn what causes what. And yours isn't different it's just vaguely described: you claim yours is different than the original, but the original **meets your description**!

Comment: I never said the original setup was symmetric; *I wasn't talking about the original setup*. This proves even more that this discussion is futile.

Comment: @Angelorf Your fourth comment to this answer says your problem is symmetric, but it is just vague. It also claims that you can't measure accelerations, you can. They happen and can be measured. It just that you are being vague about what happened, you have to say how things accelerate (if you are describing a problem). Or they have to happen and you can measure then to see that they happen (if the problem really happens in real life).

Comment: If I say how things accelerate I'm directly bypassing the problem. The question is on what basis we can say the one accelerates and the other doesn't. It's not the acceleration with respect to each other, since in that respect the situation is symmetric. So if relative distance and time considerations cannot be trusted to give acceleration, how could we have even matched the output of an accelerometer to actual acceleration? So the question really does come down to: how do you know the one is accelerating and the other isn't?

Comment: Just updated my question. I hope it's more clear now.

Comment: @Angelorf A question isn't clear until you select a physics concept you want to learn and then communicate that choice to people.

Comment: It's about the concept of *acceleration*.

Comment: @Angelorf But you understand that just fine, as indicated in your own answer. There is a 4d spacetime manifold whose 4d points are called events. Particles have worldlines on the manifold which are parameterized curves on the manifold. The unit tangents to the worldlines are the four-velocities, and the unit comes from a bilinear form on the manifold with a Lorentzian signature. The 4 accelerations say how a worldline's unit tangent (the four velocity) changes. Those accelerations are determined by forces, which as I said are always between things at the same event. That's how one does SR.

Comment: You use concepts which I'm not familiar with. I need to do some reading up before I can understand and reply to your last comment.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33965/discussion-on-answer-by-timaeus-stripped-twin-paradox).

Answer (score -5):

The one accelerating ***through the aether***.

Though you cannot say either Alice or Bob to be *moving* through the aether, you *cay* say one is accelerating through the aether, according to [Einstein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luminiferous_aether#Einstein.27s_views_on_the_aether).
"[The aether] can be used to give physical reality to acceleration and rotation."

Comment: The aether has been introduced and debunked countless times.

Comment: @HDE226868 are you saying Einstein is wrong in defining the aether the way he did?